# Rails 5 Forms Not Submitting

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and am using the bootstrap-form gem. Everything was working fine until a few days ago. Now, whenever I try to create or edit a form, whether I hit submit or cancel, the completed form page simply pops up again. From the terminal, It looks as though the information is being entered into the database, but then there is a big red ROLLBACK and when I click out of the form and go to the dashboard the information is not there. This is happening in both the development and production environments. Checked routes, all looks good.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Since there is a rollback your data might run into some validation issue. Have you checked with binding.pry and manually bang saving the object and see what causes the rollback?

Comment: Between you and me and everyone else on stack overflow, I haven't been coding for that long and have no idea what that means. But I will figure it out and see if that works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @StevenF. I think the suggestion is to open a console and create the object in the console to see if an error is thrown. The "bang" (which is the exclamation point) is to ensure the exception is thrown e.g. `Post.create!(title: "Test title")`

Comment: I understood that and I think it actually worked because I found an error that may tell me how to fix it. Maybe. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lovely that you found it out. Usually I try to be not to precise so people start digging docs and figure it out themself so at some point everything will come together ... BAM Senior! :)